# HTML containing a collapsible recursive directory listing

Tags: html, directory, dropbox, public

I would like to generate a single (static) HTML file which would display in a browser a recursive directory listing that features collapsible subdirectories.

Currently, I am using tree in the following manner:

```
tree -H http://dl.dropbox.com/u/<user_id> > web/directory_listing.html
```

This produces a HTML recursive directory (and file) listing. For the purposes of clarity, I would like directory contents collapsed by default. When a directory is selected, the directories and files in the selected directory expand and appear in the same page.

Is there some way in which I could generate this type of HTML? Perhaps the output of tree could be modified. The reason I want a single HTML file listing is because I don't have a lot of server control (this is for hosting on Dropbox).

Thanks muchly for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck using something like `tree`, perhaps add some javascript to achieve your element show/hide effects. This can easily be achieved by concatenating a javascript file on the end of your tree HTML (`tree -H`) output.

```
tree -H http://dl.dropbox.com/u/<user_id> > web/directory_listing_part.html
cat web/directory_listing_part.html web/some_file_containing_your_javascript_code > web/directory_listing.html
```

You could even use the javascript to provide additional styling if you like.

Take a look at this page:

http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/00Tree.html

This gives a good example of the sort of formats you can achieve.  Note the use of class names which should easily give you something to hook into with javascript/jquery